# What regex will match these lines?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, and sorry for the title, but I am parsing a PDF to a CSV and I've decided to go with a regex for each line due to the erratic format.

I've added , to denote where the matches should be. If you take them out, that is the raw string. The first line is the standard and the others are some of the ways missing columns can show up. Taking a look at the regex is kind of a good hint

It needs to match:

```
12,      16:00:30,  P,  14,     ______________  ABC12345678,          N,     
JOE B'obby,                    MY COMPANY-23 / NAME,                  23,  2


212,      14:00:30,,    212,     ______________  ABC12345678,          NCh,     
BOB Joe Joe,                    MY NAME,                  300,    12,      


2,      13:00:30,  P,  2,     ______________  ABC12345678,,          BOB 
Joe °,,, 20    


3,      15:15:00,  P,  132,     ______________  ABC12345678,,          PHO
Guy Guy °,,,,
```

This is what I have so far.

```
    sl_re = r'(\d+)' \
        r'[ ]+(\d+:\d+:\d+)' \
        r'[ ]+([P]*)' \
        r'[ ]+(\d+)' \
        r'[ ]+([_ ]+[A-Z]+\d+)' \
        r'[ ]+([A-Za-z]{,3}|[ ])' \
        r'[ ]+([\w\']+[ ][\w\'°]+[ ]{,1}[\w\'°]*[ ]{,1}[\w\'°]*)'\
        r'[ ]*([\w\-/ ]*|[ ])' \
        r'[ ]*(\d*|[ ])' \
        r'[ ]*(\d*$)'
```

It matches everything up until the last 3 groups perfect, but the third to last group is too greedy and will match it all

Comment: What do you intend for the third to last group to actually match? The regex will match anything including a space, or just a space -- why is the alternation with just a space even necessary, and how do you expect it to know when to stop matching? If the last two groups are not optional, you can't have `*` in them.

Comment: The last three groups are optional. The last and second to last only need to match numbers. The third to last needs to match any of these characters:

[A-Z0-9-/ .,]

i.e

"MY COMPANY-23 / NAME, K.T.R" I'm not sure how I expect it to stop matching, I was wondering if you had an idea

Comment: The simple way to fill the last two is to make the star non-greedy in the third to last group, but code which doesn't do what you want isn't really a good way to tell us what you *do* want.

Comment: Right, sorry. Some users have a company name and two more numbers that need to be matched afterward, some users have no company name and the two numbers, some users have a company name and no two numbers, It can be any combination of the three.

Comment: The way you are phrasing it sounds like the last two are in a hierarchy. If there is only one trailing number, which group should get it? The answer should allow you to change the regex from "maybe a number followed by maybe a number" to something a little more complex (optionally a sequence of two numbers, where however the first is optional? or whatever)

Comment: If there is only one trailing number, the last group should get it. I tried to make that happen with the $ character, but I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: Sounds like the end should be `r'(?:(?:(\d+) )?(\d+))?$'` then. You probably still have to change from `*` to `*?` in the third-to last group (and probably remove the nonsensical `|[ ]` but that's basically harmless)? The `$` anchor makes *something* align with the end of line but if that something is completely optional, you are not forcing anything. The regex engine can't read your mind so you really have to spell out exactly what you mean. Briefly, if something has a `*` then you are saying skip this if you can unless you have additional constraints around it.

Comment: (The last sentence isn't strictly true in the technical sense, but I'm thinking it would help shape your thinking here. If several things are optional, you have to add some guidance as to what to skip if *something* is there and needs to be matched.)

Comment: @tripleee I see, that makes sense. Definitely still learning.

With the non-greeedy company name and your end I am getting

   'BOB Joe ', '                    MY COMPANY NAME                                     2', '', '2'

From

   BOB Joe                      MY COMPANY NAME                                     2   
   2

Comment: I guess maybe you want the `[ ]` before `(?:` if you didn't put that already.

Comment: Is that pdf taken from any kind of database you have access to? Because than, there should be a more appropriate export format, that you could use for your purpose.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your help! I was able to get it working by changing a few things to be more explicit/less greedy like you suggested.

Comment: @Igle I wish. If there was, I wouldn't have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out some sort of regex :)

Comment: Maybe post your solution as an answer and accept it (eventually ... IIRC you can't do that immediately) to get some closure here and perhaps help future visitors with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from @tripleee, I figured out a way to solve it. The issue, as he suggested, was just being more explicit.

Because there are a lot of optional and un-foreseeable group combinations that require * (0 or more), it was important to make sure that they were non-greedy where possible. Using greedy searches only when I want them to match everything they possibly can (the spaces in between the groups) and non-greedy when I want it to stop at the next match. Very basic, but it was a good learning opportunity!

Only the last few lines changed, with a few chars added in that I found were needed through test cases:

```
r'([\d\.]+)'
r'[ ]+(\d+:\d+:\d+)'
r'[ ]+([P]*)'
r'[ ]+(\d+)'
r'[ ]+([_ ]+[A-Z]+\d+)'
r'[ ]+([NWCSLh]{,3}|[ ])'
    r'[ ]+([\w\'\-]+[ ]*?[\w©\'\-°]+[ ]*?[\w\'\-°]*'
    r'[ ]*?[\w\'\-°]*[ ]*?[\w\'\-°]*)'
r'[ ]*([A-Z0-9,\'\-\/ \.]*?)'
r'[ ]*([\d\-]*?)'
r'[ ]*([\d\-]*$)'
```